# Android: Lining up Views in TableRow programatically

Tags: android, android-layout

An activity in my application (my first attempt at one) generates several table rows each containing a couple of EditTexts and a Button. But, the button always appears to be misaligned, resulting in [this problem](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1623843/misalignment.jpg) - the delete buttons are shifted slightly downwards.

The relevant part of the xml layout is as follows:

```
<ScrollView
  android:id="@+id/countEditList"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
  <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/countEditLayout"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <!-- insert the new rows here as they are created -->
  </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The code which creates each row from a database cursor does the following:

```
TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

EditText title = new EditText(this);
title.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
title.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

EditText counting = new EditText(this);
counting.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
counting.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

Button deleteCount = new Button(this);
deleteCount.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
deleteCount.setText(R.string.deleteCount);
deleteCount.setOnClickListener(this);
deleteCount.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

row.addView(title);
row.addView(counting);
row.addView(deleteCount);
layout.addView(row,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)); // Earlier: layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.countEditLayout);
```

I suspect that I should somehow be setting the layout_gravity of the EditTexts and Button but I can't work out how to do that - would anyone be able to offer any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could adjust Edit Texts positioning using some padding:

```
title.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
counting.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to change the relative alignment of the deleteCount button within the row. Should I perhaps be using some other sort of layout for this, rather than a table?

Comment: Finally got it! row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); looks like it does the trick.